# Minimum number of comparisons to sort k elements among n

Tags: complexity-theory, sorting

In *The Art of Computer Programming* D. Knuth, in section 5.3.3 *Minimum Comparison Selection* defines :

- $V_t(n)$ as the minimum number of comparisons needed to find the $t^{th}$ largest element of $n$ numbers
- $W_t(n)$ as the minimum number of comparisons needed to find and sort the $t$ largest elements of $n$ numbers

Then, there is a table (Table 1.) that gives all values of $V_t(n)$ for $n\le 10$

My questions :

1. Is there an updated table for known values of $V_t(n)$ somewhere ? (last results used by Knuth are from 1996).
2. Is there a similar table for $W_t(n)$ ?

Comment: It might be a fun exercise if you try to write a program to compute that table.